# How to transfer Number to Character in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

How to transfer Number to Character in Google Apps Script?

```
var test=(char)number;
```

Can't work....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
String.fromCharCode(number)
```